# No module named _osmosdr_swig

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr, gnuradio, usrp

I am trying to run GnuRadio python code in my python web server and got the "No module named _osmosdr_swig" error. Please, what is the cause for this error?

I know it sounds like so obvious that I need to have the 'osmosdr-swig' package but I searched online trying to figure out how to add it but no luck.

[image]

My python code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##################################################
# GNU Radio Python Flow Graph
# Title: Exercise 1
# GNU Radio version: 3.7.13.5
##################################################

from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import audio
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import filter
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from optparse import OptionParser
import osmosdr
import time



class Exercise_1(gr.top_block):

    def __init__(self):
        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Exercise 1")

        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 10000000
        self.channel_width = channel_width = 200e3
        self.channel_freq = channel_freq = 96.5e6
        self.center_freq = center_freq = 97.9e6

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.rational_resampler_xxx_0 = filter.rational_resampler_ccc(
                interpolation=12,
                decimation=5,
                taps=None,
                fractional_bw=None,
        )
        self.osmosdr_source_0 = osmosdr.source( args="numchan=" + str(1) + " " + '' )
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_sample_rate(samp_rate)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_center_freq(center_freq, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_freq_corr(0, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_dc_offset_mode(0, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_iq_balance_mode(0, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_gain_mode(False, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_gain(0, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_if_gain(20, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_bb_gain(20, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_antenna('', 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_bandwidth(0, 0)

        self.low_pass_filter_0 = filter.fir_filter_ccf(int(samp_rate / channel_width), firdes.low_pass(
            1, samp_rate, 75e3, 25e3, firdes.WIN_HAMMING, 6.76))
        self.blocks_multiply_xx_0 = blocks.multiply_vcc(1)
        self.audio_sink_0 = audio.sink(48000, '', True)
        self.analog_wfm_rcv_0 = analog.wfm_rcv(
            quad_rate=480e3,
            audio_decimation=10,
        )
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_c(samp_rate, analog.GR_COS_WAVE, center_freq - channel_freq, 1, 0)



        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_sig_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_multiply_xx_0, 1))
        self.connect((self.analog_wfm_rcv_0, 0), (self.audio_sink_0, 0))
        self.connect((self.blocks_multiply_xx_0, 0), (self.low_pass_filter_0, 0))
        self.connect((self.low_pass_filter_0, 0), (self.rational_resampler_xxx_0, 0))
        self.connect((self.osmosdr_source_0, 0), (self.blocks_multiply_xx_0, 0))
        self.connect((self.rational_resampler_xxx_0, 0), (self.analog_wfm_rcv_0, 0))

    def get_samp_rate(self):
        return self.samp_rate

    def set_samp_rate(self, samp_rate):
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_sample_rate(self.samp_rate)
        self.low_pass_filter_0.set_taps(firdes.low_pass(1, self.samp_rate, 75e3, 25e3, firdes.WIN_HAMMING, 6.76))
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_sampling_freq(self.samp_rate)

    def get_channel_width(self):
        return self.channel_width

    def set_channel_width(self, channel_width):
        self.channel_width = channel_width

    def get_channel_freq(self):
        return self.channel_freq

    def set_channel_freq(self, channel_freq):
        self.channel_freq = channel_freq
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_frequency(self.center_freq - self.channel_freq)

    def get_center_freq(self):
        return self.center_freq

    def set_center_freq(self, center_freq):
        self.center_freq = center_freq
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_center_freq(self.center_freq, 0)
        self.analog_sig_source_x_0.set_frequency(self.center_freq - self.channel_freq)


def main(top_block_cls=Exercise_1, options=None):

    tb = top_block_cls()
    tb.start()
    try:
        raw_input('Press Enter to quit: ')
    except EOFError:
        pass
    tb.stop()
    tb.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: same as last time: not properly installed, or pybombs env not activated.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Thanks Marcus, I was about to reinstall a fresh OS then try again.